# On adjugate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In Goldman's paper Curvature formulas for implicit curves and surfaces, he defines adjugate matrix for row vector and column vector as follows:

$\begin{gathered}
  {k^*} = k \hfill \\
  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{r_1}}&{{r_2}} 
\end{array}} \right)^*} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - {r_2}} \\ 
  {{r_1}} 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{c_1}} \\ 
  {{c_2}} 
\end{array}} \right)^*} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{c_2}}&{ - {c_1}} 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
  {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{m_{11}}}&{{m_{12}}} \\ 
  {{m_{21}}}&{{m_{22}}} 
\end{array}} \right)^*} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{m_{22}}}&{ - {m_{21}}} \\ 
  { - {m_{12}}}&{{m_{11}}} 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

I don't know why he defines so. And I can't see why these identities hold:

$\begin{gathered}
  {c^*}{r^*} = rc \hfill \\
  (Mc) = {c^*}{M^*} \hfill \\
  {(rM)^*} = {M^*}{r^*} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the goal of introducing the adjugate in the paper? The main goal of the adjugate in my experience is in writing down the formula for the inverse: you have $A \operatorname{Adj}(A)=\operatorname{det}(A) I$.

Comment: Can you write the formula? I would imagine it is related to the inverse in some simple manner.

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question: can you write how the adjugate is connected to the curvature formula?

Answer (score 0):

Why he defines the adjugate is something I can answer without reading the paper myself. As for the identities: try multiplying them out. For example:

$$r = \begin{pmatrix}r_1&r_2\end{pmatrix}\qquad c=\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{align}rc &= \begin{pmatrix}r_1&r_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=(r_1c_1 + r_2c_2)\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}c^*r^* &= \begin{pmatrix}c_1&-c_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}r_1\\-r_2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=(c_1r_1 + (-c_2)(-r_2))\\
&=(r_1c_1 + r_2c_2)\end{align}$$
So $c^*r^* = rc$. You can do the rest.